# Checking applied drawable in Android

Tags: android

I want to check the Image button (`btn_a`), if it contain `selected_image` or `unselected_image`.

Then I want to change the `selected_image` to `unselect_image` or `unselect_image` to `selected_image` by the click of the Image Button.

My code so far:

```
        btn_a = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_a);
    btn_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(btn_a.getResources().getDrawable(R.id.button_a)==R.drawable.unselected_image){
                btn_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_image);
                }else{
                btn_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.unselected_image);
                }

        }
    });
```

But this shows an error `btn_a.getResources().getDrawable(R.id.button_a)==R.drawable.unselected_image`.

Help me to implement this correctly.

**EDIT :**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_cell, null);
    }
    btn_a = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_a);
    btn_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Drawable drawable = favourite.getDrawable();
            if(drawable.getConstantState().equals(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_image).getConstantState())){
                btn_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.unselected_image);
            }else{
                btn_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_image);
            }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: It worked or not @tenten ??

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

hey Create context object first

In your Class Globally Declare this

```
Context context
```

then After add thiss

```
btn_a = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_a);
btn_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Drawable drawable = btn_a.getDrawable();
     if (drawable.getConstantState().equals(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_image).getConstantState())){
   //Do your work here
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: `if (drawable.getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_image).getConstantState())){` shows errors

Comment: shows this : the method getResources() is undifined for the type new View.onclickListner

Comment: should u use selector??

Comment: This button is in the cell of my custom list view. I want to pass position of my list view, so this code can function properly. How can I pass position here?

Comment: in this it take position its self

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113897/discussion-between-aanal-shah-and-tenten).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    btn_a = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_a);
    btn_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Bitmap b1 = ((BitmapDrawable)btn_a.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Bitmap unselected_image = ((BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_image)).getBitmap();
            Bitmap selected_image = ((BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_image)).getBitmap();
             // You will need minimum API level as 12 for using this sameAs function
            if(b1.sameAs(unselected_image))
            {
                btn_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_image);
            }else{
                btn_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.unselected_image);
            }

        }
    });
```

This will solve your problem. **I am comparing bitmaps here**..!!

> EDIT 1:

Declare an Integer ArrayList :

```
 ArrayList<Integer> favList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Initialize it in your constructor :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++) {
        favList.add(R.drawable.unselected_image);
    }
```

Change your getView like this:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_cell, null);
    }
    btn_a = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_a);
    btn_a.setTag(position);
    btn_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Drawable drawable = favourite.getDrawable();
            if (drawable.getConstantState().equals(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_image).getConstantState())) {
                favList.set((Integer)v.getTag(),R.drawable.unselected_image);
            } else {
                favList.set((Integer)v.getTag(),R.drawable.selected_image);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
    favourite.setImageResource(favList.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: shows this : the method getResources() is undifined for the type new View.onclickListner

Comment: Are you having context object ?? I think this is your Adapter code right??

Comment: `Bitmap b1 = ((BitmapDrawable)btn_a.getDrawable()).getBitmap();` shows error. `.getBitmap()` is not poping up.

Comment: what is `notifyDataSetChanged ()`

Comment: Is it giving any error ?? `notifyDataSetChanged();` is used to refersh the Adapter..!!

Comment: shows java.util.arraylist.throwIndexoutofbound exception  invalid index 0,size is 0 in line `favourite.setImageResource(favList.get(position));`

Comment: have you initialized the list in your constructor?? as i said ?? if yes show me the initialization code..!!